# Composition of linear operators and ranks...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:V \rightarrow W$ and $g:W \rightarrow X$ are linear operators, with spaces $V$,$W$ and $X$ having dimensions $n$,$k$, $m$, resp. Suppose rank$f$=$r_f$, and rank$g$=$r_g$. What are the possible ranks of the composition $gf$?

I used the kernel theorem that tells me all I need to do is sum the kernel dimension of $f$ with the kernel dimension of $imf \bigcap kerg$ to find the kernel dimension of the composition. However, what do I do when the image of $f$ and kernel of $g$ only partially intersect?

Comment: All ranks between $0$ and $\min \{r_f,\,r_g\}$ (both inclusive) are possible. To find the rank, you must know $\dim \ker (g\circ f)$.

Comment: Can you explain why? My answer is much different and depends on n and k.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $g|_{im f}$ the restriction of $g$ to $im f$ then by the rank nullity theorem we have
$$\dim im f=rank f=\dim im( g|_{im f})+\dim \ker g|_{im f}=\dim im( gf)+\dim\ker g\cap im f$$
hence 
$$rank (gf)=rank(f)-\dim\ker g\cap im f\tag{1}$$
so by $(1)$ and since $im(gf)\subset im(g)$ we have clearly 
$$rank(gf)\leq \min(rank(f),rank(g))\tag{*}$$
moreover since $\ker g\cap im f\subset \ker g$ so by the rank nullity theorem we have
$$\dim \ker g\cap im f\leq k-rank(g)$$
and finally by $(1)$ we have
$$rank(gf)\geq rank(f)+rank(g)-k\tag{**}$$
hence $(*)$ and $(**)$ gives
$$rank(f)+rank(g)-k\leq rank(gf)\leq \min(rank(f),rank(g))$$

Comment: Where does your second equality in line 1 come from?

Comment: taking the restriction of $g$ as I explained then its domain is $im f$ so $\ker g|_{im f}=\ker g\cap im f$ and you can prove this equality by double inclusion and ditto we prove that $im g|_{im f}=im(gf)$

Comment: I'm sorry, I typed that wrong, I understand your first line. I meant your first *. Where does that second inequality come from?

Comment: Since $\ker g\cap im f\subset \ker g$ then $\dim \ker g\cap im f\leq \dim\ker g =k-rank g$ by the rank nullity theorem applied to $g$.